# This code isn't working (for no reason)?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, meteor, account

This code is from this tutorial: https://waaave.com/tutorial/meteor/design-a-complete-authentication-system-with-meteor/#L11

it's step 6.1 and as far as I can tell there are no errors but for some reason it doesn't work and the "Forgot Password" link does nothing when I click on it. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Javascript:

```
Template.main.helpers({
    showForgotPassword: function() {
        return Session.get('showForgotPassword');
    }
});

// Sign In Template
Template.signIn.events({
    'submit #signInForm': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var signInForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            email = trimInput(signInForm.find('.email').val().toLowerCase()),
            password = signInForm.find('.password').val();

        if (isNotEmpty(email) && isEmail(email) && isNotEmpty(password) && isValidPassword(password)) {
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    Session.set('alert', 'We\'re sorry but these credentials are not valid.');
                } else {
                    Sesson.set('alert', 'Welcome back New Meteorite!');

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    },

      'click #showForgotPassword': function(e, t) {
        Session.set('showForgotPassword', true);
        return false;
    },

});
```

Html:

```
<div id="topbar">
            {{> signOut}}
     {{#unless resetPassword}}
         {{#unless currentUser}}
             {{#unless showForgotPassword}}
             {{else}}
                  {{> forgotPassword}}
             {{/unless}}
         {{else}}
          {{/unless}}
     {{else}}
         {{> resetPassword}}
     {{/unless}}
    </div>

<template name="signIn">
            <a class="show-forgot-password" href="javascript:void(0);" id="showForgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
    <div class="sign-in" id="signIn">
        <form action="/signin" class="sign-in-form" id="signInForm" method="post">
            <input class="email" id="signInEmail" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="password" id="signInPassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input class="btn btn-success" id"signInButton" type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end .sign-in -->
</template>

<template name="signOut">
    <div class="connected">
        <a class="sign-out" href="/" id="signOut">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
    <!-- end .connected -->
</template>

<template name="signUp">
    <div class="sign-up">
        <form action="/sign-up" class="sign-up-form" id="signUpForm" method="post">
            <input class="username" id="signUpUsername" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" >
            <input class="email" id="signUpEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" >
            <input class="password" id="signUpPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            <input class="password-confirm" id="signUpPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign up for Chattly">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end .sign-up -->
</template>

<template name="forgotPassword">
    <div class="forgot-password" id="forgotPassword">
        <a class="return-to-sign-in" href="javascript:void(0);" id="returnToSignIn">Return</a>
        <form action="/forgot" class="forgot-password-form" id="forgotPasswordForm" method="post">
            <input class="email" id="forgotPasswordEmail" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end .forgot-password -->
</template>

<template name="resetPassword">
    <div class="reset-password">
        <h2 class="headline">You're now saved, <span class="bold">follow the light!</span></h2>
        <h3 class="details">You just have to type and confirm your new password to regain access to your dashboard.</h3>
        <form action="/reset-password" class="reset-password-form" id="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
            <input class="password" id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="Your New Password" type="password" >
            <input class="password-confirm" id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm New Password" type="password" >
            <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end .reset-password -->
</template>
```

Comment: check the console for any scripting errors.@5AMWE5T

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'helpers' of undefined ui.js?17756159fe4e9a6e2a8c004dbbb8c22b0ed5f29a:170

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'publish' users.js?bb47c4d55c2aea6f0ebc3c61b1c10283cb7196e4:5

Comment: Also when I hover over the 'Forgot Password' link it says javascript:void(0); is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @5AMWE5T yes, that's there to prevenet default anchor click action so that the click handler can capture the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point (6.1) in the tutorial, you have not yet configured any event handlers for the `forgotPassword`. It is not working because the code is not there yet.

In the following section, 6.2, the author walks you through sending an email for initiating password recovery:

```
Template.forgotPassword.events({
    'submit #forgotPasswordForm': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var forgotPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            email = trimInput(forgotPasswordForm.find('#forgotPasswordEmail').val().toLowerCase());

        if (isNotEmpty(email) && isEmail(email)) {
            Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
                        Session.set('alert', 'This email does not exist.');
                    } else {
                        Session.set('alert', 'We\'re sorry but something went wrong.');
                    }
                } else {
                    Session.set('alert', 'Email Sent. Please check your mailbox to reset your password.');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    },

    'click #returnToSignIn': function(e, t) {
        Session.set('showForgotPassword', null);
        return false;
    },
});
```

This is a common pattern I've been seeing in recent tutorials.

Instead of giving you a complete app in the beginning and breaking it down, the authors take an iterative approach and build the app piece by piece, which is what you normally would do if you were to build the app.

So it works perfectly as a tutorial. Just be patient until the end :)

UPDATE:
Th forgot password form is not showing up because it is supposed to be within a template called main as seen in this code:

```
<template name="main">
    {{> alert}}
    {{#unless resetPassword}}
        {{#unless currentUser}}
            {{#unless showForgotPassword}}
                {{> signIn}}
                {{> signUp}}
            {{else}}
                {{> forgotPassword}}
            {{/unless}}
        {{else}}
            {{> signOut}}
        {{/unless}}
    {{else}}
        {{> resetPassword}}
    {{/unless}}
</template>
```

and the following helper takes the session paramater and feeds it to the `unless` block:

```
Template.main.helpers({
    showForgotPassword: function() {
        return Session.get('showForgotPassword');
    }
});
```

but your code does not have that `main` template, instead you wrapped your code in a generic `div` and you also seem to have changed some other portions of the code.

```
<div id="topbar">
            {{> signOut}}
     {{#unless resetPassword}}
         {{#unless currentUser}}
             {{#unless showForgotPassword}}
             {{else}}
                  {{> forgotPassword}}
             {{/unless}}
         {{else}}
          {{/unless}}
     {{else}}
         {{> resetPassword}}
     {{/unless}}
    </div>
```

Therefore, you can either use the original code from the tutorial, or if you really want to change that code, you can wrap your `topbar div` with a `main template` as seen in the original code.

Comment: The problem is that when I click the forgot password link the form doesn't show up at all like it should. I haven't yet tried getting the email to send

Comment: @5AMWE5T I updated the answer. Your code is missing the `<template name="main">` tag around your topbar div.